# Why is B-H curve preferred to B-B_vac curve?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic, magnetics, hysteresis

Can someone please tell me why we use H in the \$B-H\$ curve?

I initially thought

1. \$H\$ was the field strength of the field developed in a vacuum when a current is passed through a coil (placed in vacuum), and
2. \$B\$ is the corresponding field strength in the core (when the coil is wound around something) for the same current,

If that were the case \$H\$ and \$B\$ would've been equal in a vacuum, but that's not the case, then what is the actual definition of \$H\$? (I understand that \$H\$ is current times turns divided by path length, but is there a physical *intuitive* meaning for it?
)

Here's why I think \$B_{vac}\$-\$B\$ makes sense. In class, we were taught what \$B\$ is, in vacuum(\$B_{vac}\$) and did a bunch of exercises. Then a material was introduced and we added relative permeability to account for its addition. When we got to the hysteresis curve part, the professor got rid of the constant term in \$B_{vac}\$ and used the term \$H\$. Why couldn't we continue with \$B\$? If we did continue with \$B\$, the x-axis would be \$B_{vac}\$ and y-axis remains \$B\$ with relative permeability as the slope. **Why is this not preferred to \$B\$-\$H\$ curve?**  \$B_{vac}\$ - \$B\$ seems to be intuitive for the comparison with \$B_{core}\$.

On retrospection, the question narrows down to **What's the purpose of \$B\$-\$H\$ curve?** It's to find the \$B\$ in core for a particular current supplied, correct? If yes, what advantage does \$H\$ hold over using \$B_{vac}\$ in the magnetization curve.

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer here, but B and H are two different but related fields--look back to Maxwell's equations and how the two are treated differently.

Comment: \$H\$ is more like a *cause* and  \$B\$ (vacuum or otherwise) is like an effect. So \$B-H\$ curve is like an graph between cause and effect. \$B-B_{\text{vac}}\$ would be like ratio between outputs foe different medium.

Comment: B is produced by aligning the ferromagnetic domains caused by H. H is the original magnetic field driving everything and it causing the domains to align themselves gives it a boost which ends up as B.

Comment: I guess you will find both in datasheets.. \$H\$ and \$B_{vac}\$ are fully proportional. Having done research in magnetism in the past, I consider Tesla the more usual unit. Journals incentivize the use of \$H\$ and \$A/m\$, but as a middleground you also see \$µ_0 H\$ given in units of Tesla.

Answer (score 3):

From a practical point of view, here's what tends to help me:

I like use the words

- "magnetic field strength" for H

and

- "magnetic flux density" for B.

A coil wound around a core causes a magnetic field strength and will cause a flux density within the core's material. The relationship is the core's relative permeability µ<sub>r</sub>, and the B-H curve shows this relationship.

When your professor switched from B<sub>vac</sub> to B, the intention was to show how a magnetic material behaves differently compared to vacuum, I assume.

What this approach does not explain is how a medium can be magnetized using an external magnetic field (which, in turn, is proportional to the current of a coil). I find it useful to remember that a curve for B<sub>vac</sub>-H will be a straight line, representing a vacuum's magnetic property B<sub>vac</sub> = µ<sub>0</sub> * H. Even in this case, the "driving force" for the vacuum's *magnetic flux density* B<sub>vac</sub> is the *magnetic field strength* H.

The driving "force" that magnetizes (and, eventually, saturates) a magnetic core, is a magnetic field (H), and not an external flux density.

Comment: I agree. I think using \$B_{vac}\$ on the magnetic field axis comes from the tradition in material sciences, because it neatly shows the permeability. E.g. a material might acquire a magnetization of 2 T in an external field of only "2 mT" (which written out correctly would be "2 mT/µ0"). So the relative permeability can be inferred directly to be ~1000. Nowadays it is more usual to write \$µ_0H\$ instead of \$B_{vac}\$, which emphasizes that it is indeed the \$H\$ field.

Comment: An interesting characteristic of certain ferrites is that the magnetization of the material - the B field - remains after the magnetizing force - the H field - is removed.  I do not know if this applies to all ferrous materials or not.

Comment: @tobalt I think your comment is very helpful. I'll edit B_vac = µ_0 * H into my answer...

Comment: @SteveSh This is the remanence. It is high for permanent magnets (in the case of ferrites, they are called "hard ferrites") and it is low for what's often called "soft" magnetic materials or ferrites. Old core memory uses little toroids made from hard ferrites, and the bits are stored in the magnetization (remanence). For modern coils or inductors used in voltage converters, a low remanence is desireable, because the area within the loop of a B-H curve is proportional to the magnetic losses of a power transformer or inductor. The lower the remancence, the smaller the loop.

Comment: @SteveSh yes essentially all macroscopic magnetic materials have remanance. In case of digital magnetic storage, or permanent magnets, the desired remanence is 100%. In case of transformers, the desired remanence and hysteresis is 0. It is actually a challenge to engineer macroscopic materials with almost no remanence.

Answer (score 2):

This a bit old, but for anybody having the same question, it is due historical and field of study reasons.

- In Physics, the literature regard B as the fundamental, and H as
  something secondary.
- In Engineering is the opposite, H is the fundamental and B is secondary, as H is produced by the current, which is paramount in Electrical and Electronics Engineering, especially in Power Electronics. In this case B is a produced value that must be controlled to avoid saturation and losses.

Also, B-Bvac works for the vacuum. And although, as you said, you introduce the relative pemeability when there is a material with some ferromagnetism, it is not constant.

The permeability decreases with an increase in the absolute value of H field, reaching a point of saturation where it is 1, and a non-negligible increase of H field creates a negligible increase of B field (as happens in the vacuum).

Additionally, the permeability also varies with the temperature, the frequency of the field and the offset value of H field (produced by a current DC value different from 0).

As you can see, there is plenty of reason to use the H field in Engineering. And many (though sadly not all) of these dependencies are reflected in the B-H curve provided by the magnetic core manufacturers.

If anybody is interested in reading further about the historial reasons, I recommend this article:
[Confusion between B and H](https://e-magnetica.pl/confusion_between_b_and_h)

Comment: Link only answers are frowned upon.  Can you summarize the fine points that other answers missed?  Otherwise, I recommend deleting this, and when you have enough priv, enter it as a comment on the most relevant answer, or on the question

Comment: I couldn't comment at that time (I just got it), but I didn't know about the link only answers, I will expandi it

Comment: My impression is exactly opposite, so I guess your answer is only one opinion. Physicists use the \$H\$ as the fundamental field (older ones may still use \$B\$ for supposedly more "natural" units). And IMO engineers don't care about \$H\$ at all, because, as your write, the only real effect is avoiding core saturation (\$B\$)

Comment: Nomenclature is always relative, but that's why I added the link, where you can find many references supporting what I wrote, Feynman and Jiles, among others. So it is an opinion, but not just mine.
About caring only for B, that is true for generalistic Power Engineers; but Magnetic Engineers have to care and design for H:
It's the H field what saturates the core.
It's the H DC bias what drops the inductance of a powder core.
it's the H field from the fringing flux that induces current and losses in turns near the gap.
It's the H field from other turns that generate proximity losses.